# convergence in probability: speed of convergence

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I am not sure if the title appropriately describes the question. I will appreaciate any ideas.

Suppose $\{X_n:n\geq 1\}$ is a sequence of random variables defined on a common probability space. Assume that $X_n\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} 0$.

I need to prove the following: **there will exist a sequence** $\{a_n:n\geq 1\}$, such that $a_n\downarrow 0$, and
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n|>a_n) = 0.
$$
Obviously, not every sequence $\{a_n\}$ converging to zero will satisfy the above condition, but how does one find such a sequence.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can construct a sequence $a_n$ s.t. $P\{|X_n|>a_n\}\le a_n$, e.g. repeat each item of some sequence converging to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment. Take a sequence $\{k^{-1}:k\ge 1\}$. For each $k$ there exists $n_k$ s.t.

$$P\{|X_n|>k^{-1}\}\le k^{-1}$$

for all $n\ge n_k$. So, the corresponding $\{a_n\}$ is constructed as follows: for $n_{k-1}\le n < n_k$, $a_n=k^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is very much like, $P(|X_n|>\epsilon)\leq \epsilon$, for large enough $n$.